# (Python) 2D Array Checkers - How to Jump and take opponent's piece

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, coordinates

So I have a very basic game board:

```
  B W B W            with assigned coordinates of       1  2  3  4
  W B W B                                               5  6  7  8
  B W B W                                               9  10 11 12
```

This game isn't actually checkers, but similar. The users each select a piece(B or W) to remove before game starts. So we would be starting with something like this:

```
   - W B W
   W B W B
   B - B W
```

Next, the users will be able to 'jump' over the other user's piece. The jump can only be horizontal or vertical, no diagonal jumping aloud. So I'm starting off by capturing what coordinate of the piece the user is selecting, as well as the destination coordinate where they will land after their jump:

```
   Bjump = input(BLACK, first select the coordinate of the piece you want to move as well as the coordinate where you would like to land. Please Separate Coordinates with a SINGLE space: ")
```

The user needs to be able select the B @ coordinate '3', jump over the W @ 2, and land @ coordinate 1. This processes should not only jump the B piece over the W piece, but remove the W piece that it jumped @ coordinate 2. Replacing it with a '-'

Giving the output:

```
  B - - W
  W B W B
  B - B W
```

My first thoughts were to do something like this:

```
   if(Bjump == "3 1"):
    if(grid[0][1] == 'W'):
        if(grid[0][2] == 'B'):
            grid[0][2] = '-'
            grid[0][1] = '-'
            grid[0][1] = 'B'
        else:
            print("oops! try again!")
   else:
        print("oops! You can only jump over W's!")
```

My issue with this is that not only am I going to have to create an if(statement) for every possible scenario, but who knows what the game board is going to be at every move of every game?

Can someone please help me wrap my mind around not only how to go about it, but how to make it "Universal" no matter how many different ways the game can be played? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece being jumped over is always average of source and target x,y coordinates. With that in mind you could write something like this:

```
board = [
    ['-', 'W', 'B', 'W'],
    ['W', 'B', 'W', 'B'],
    ['B', '-', 'B', 'W']
]

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(row)

def coords(board, num):
    num = int(num) - 1
    return num % len(board), num // len(board)

def jump(board, move):
    (src_x, src_y), (dst_x, dst_y) = (coords(board, x) for x in move.split())
    x_diff = abs(src_x - dst_x)
    y_diff = abs(src_y - dst_y)

    if sorted([x_diff, y_diff]) != [0, 2]:
        print('Oops, invalid coordinates')
        return

    mid_x = (src_x + dst_x) // 2
    mid_y = (src_y + dst_y) // 2

    if board[src_y][src_x] == '-':
        print('Oops, source cell empty')

    if board[dst_y][dst_x] != '-':
        print('Oops, target cell occupied')

    if board[mid_y][mid_x] == '-':
        print('Oops, no piece to jump over')

    if board[src_y][src_x] == board[mid_y][mid_x]:
        print('Oops, can\'t jump over piece with same color')

    board[dst_y][dst_x] = board[src_y][src_x]
    board[mid_y][mid_x] = '-'
    board[src_y][src_x] = '-'

move = '3 1'
print_board(board)
print('Execute move {}'.format(move))
jump(board, move)
print_board(board)
```

Output:

```
['-', 'W', 'B', 'W']
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['B', '-', 'B', 'W']
Execute move 3 1
['B', '-', '-', 'W']
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['B', '-', 'B', 'W']
```

Note that above works only on Python 3.

Comment: what does the ' j ' argument represent in the jump function?

Comment: @Ted: It's actually the whole move, renamed to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer you provided me. It was a huge help. I am taking a bit to respond as I have been analyzing and comparing your answer to my code. I have learned a lot with this as a reference. Thanks again!

Comment: I had to alter my code a bit resulting in issues with the code that you provided me. Now, the first row is indicated by the number 1, second  row the number 2, and third row the number 3. The columns are A, B , C, D. The user puts in their source coordinate which would be A3(equivient to the old 3) then a destination coordinage A1(= old 1 location).  I am getting hung up on the jump() and coords() with the error message when the function jump gets to the split(). error when it hits the split() of jump()

num = int(num) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A4'

Comment: @Ted: If column names are letters and numbers are rows `A3` would correlate to `10` in previous coordinate system. On the other hand if row names were letters and columns numbers then `A3` would equal to `3` in the original coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the board like:

```
for row in board:
print(" ".join(row))
```

...it prints the board in a nicer-looking grid that looks more like a proper GUI game type thingy. Just try it, you'll see.